# Assigning values from array to one String - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm fairly new to programming and am having trouble figuring out how to print values of an array to one continuous string.

```
if(tempScale.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
    {

    for( int index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++)
    {
       temp = temperature[index];
        tempSum += temperature[index] ++; //sum used for average calc
        tempLabel = "F";

        String temps = "";   
        temps += temps + Double.toString(temp) + " "; //this is what I would like to have printed

    }       
}
```

I would just like to check and see if these values are in fact printing correctly to one string, but if the string is not within the loops then I get the message "cannot find symbol - variable temps". Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I ultimately need the string to be outside of the loop as i will be formatting it later, as shown below.

```
System.out.print(temps);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Why `tempSum += temperature[index] ++`? That will change the content of your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of the `temps` string to just outside of the if statement. You should also use equals instead of plus equals, otherwise items will be listed in the string multiple times.

Here's a simplified example:

```
String s = "";
if (condition) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        s = s + Integer.toString(i) + " ";
    }
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply, but I ultimately need to print the string after the if condition (at the very end of my entire program), not within it. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Move the declaration of `temps` outside of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put temps outside the for loop, if you don't, every time, it will reset temps to "". Try this:

```
public static void printArray(double[] a) {

    String s="";

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        s+=Double.toString(a[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(s);

}

public static void main(String...args) {

    double[] myArray=new double[/*length*/];
    //some code to initialize array...
    printArrray(myArray);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Java 8, and assuming you have an array of doubles; then you might use a `DoubleStream` to get the average and perform your `String` concatenation. Like,

```
double[] temperature = { 32, 100 };
String tempScale = "F";
if (tempScale.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
    String temps = DoubleStream.of(temperature).mapToObj(Double::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    double average = DoubleStream.of(temperature).average().orElse(0);
    System.out.printf("%s average = %.1f%n", temps, average);
}
```

which outputs

```
32.0 100.0 average = 66.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Real quick, here is how I would sort of do it:

```
double temp = 0;
double tempSum = 0;
double tempAverage = 0;
String tempLabel = "";
String temps = ""; 

if(tempScale.equalsIgnoreCase("F")){
    tempLabel = "F";
    for( int index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++) {
        temp = temperature[index];
        tempSum += temp; //sum used for average calc
        temps += String.valueOf(temp) + tempLabel + " "; //this is what I would like to have printed
    }
    tempAverage = tempSum / (double) temperature.length;
}
```

In your case you definitely don't what to declare the **temps** string variable within the **for** loop since any string contained within it will be wiped out and reinitialized with the string data from the current iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TempScale {

public static void main(String[] asdasd) {

    String tempScale = "F";
    String temps = "";

    double[] temperature = { 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 };
    double tempSum = 0.0;
    double temp = 0.0;
    String tempLabel = "";// or null if you prefer

    if (tempScale.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {

        for (int index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++) {
            temp = temperature[index]; // this is just temperature[index]
            tempSum += temperature[index]++; // sum used for average calc
            tempLabel = "F";

            temps += temps + Double.toString(temp) + " "; // this is what I
                                                            // would like to
                                                            // have printed

        }
    }

    System.out.println("temps " + temps);
    System.out.println("tempSum " + tempSum);
    System.out.println("tempLabel " + tempLabel);
}
}
```

The Scope of the variable is the Problem. You need to declare temps, temSum , tempLabel and whatever else you need after the if code block before the if code block.

And as the others said: Declaring a variable in a loop will initialize it with the corresponding value each loop iteration.

regards